# when a port is opened in linux?

Tags: linux, process, port, bind

I am using netstat to display the open port, but I am wondering when a port is opened is it only when a bind() is invoked in a process, or it is already available and the bind just change its state to listen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a maximum number of ports in a system (depends on the OS, but in general it's 65535 or (2^16)-1), there are `privileged` ports (<1024) and there are `non-privileged` ports (>1024). Privileged ports require root permissions to use them, non-privileged allow user processes to bind. But port is considered open or used at the point when you call `bind()`. You can read up on sockets in general [at this location](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sockets.html).